# Why I get "$http:badreq"? AngularJS $http method and Zend 3 AbstractRestfulController class

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework3

The get method is AbstractRestfulController class is as follow:

```
public function get($id)
{
    $user = $this->userModelService->getUserRepository()->find($id);
    if (!$user) {
        return new JsonModel(['message' => 'No user with this ID']);
    }

    return new JsonModel([
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

and AngularJS controller is:

```
apiApp.controller('getCtrl', function getCtrl($scope, $http)
{
    var getc = this;
    getc.finalUrl = "";
    getc.mainUri = "";

    getc.sendRequest = function sendRequest(mainUrl, userId)
    {
        getc.finalUrl = 'http://user.local/user/api/1';
        //mainUrl + '/' + userId;
        $http.get({
                url: 'http://user.local/user/api/1',
                method: 'GET',
                // params: {"id": userId}
            })
            .then( function onSuccess(responce){
                getc.msgData = responce.data;
                getc.msgConfig = responce.config;
                getc.msgHeaders = responce.headers;
            } , function onError(responce){
                getc.msg = responce.statusText;
            } );
    };
});
```

I have tested the API via command-line and I get the result.

But in view side by means of AngularJS, I get a [$http:badreq](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/badreq) error!

Would you please help me to find what is wrong with this code?

Comment: If I use the first example presented in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp), I get the result, but with my code I get the badreq error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the request configuration parameter passed to the $http service is not a valid object. `$http` expects a single parameter, the request configuration object, but received a parameter that was not an object or did not contain valid properties.

The error message should provide additional context such as the actual value of the parameter that was received.

```
̶$̶h̶t̶t̶p̶.̶g̶e̶t̶(̶{̶
$http({
    url: 'http://user.local/user/api/1',
    method: 'GET',
    // params: {"id": userId}
})
```